# "Вінтаж" в офіційних документах

Tags: вживання-слів, legal-terms

Великий тлумачний словник (ВТС) сучасної української мови

> ***[Вінтаж](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53394/845800.html)*** у, ч. Не продані своєчасно колекційні речі (одяг).

В СУМ-11 слово ***вінтаж*** відсутнє.

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/vintazh) пропонують декілька заміників слова:

> осучас
>
> старосучасний
>
> старосвітній
>
> осучаслений

Чи нормативно вживати слово "вінтаж" в офіційних документах чи варто замінити на українські відповідники?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Це слово доволі недавно прийшло на терени України, тому не дивно, що у СУМі-11 його немає. Проте [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=190133&page=474) вже подає:

> **ВІНТА́Ж** , у́, ч.
>
> **1.** Речі минулих років, зібрані в колекції (одяг, взуття, вино і т. ін.). Вінтаж тим і цінний, що ексклюзивну дизайнерську, неймовірно дорогу річ із колекцій минулих років можна купити досить дешево
>   (із журн.).
>
> **2.** Напрям у дизайнерському, мистецькому та ін. стилі, якому притаманне використання тенденцій минулих часів. Актуальний сьогодні стиль вінтаж диктує свої правила: нові аромати – це вчасно згадані старі (із журн.).

Оскільки це слово зафіксоване в академічному виданні, то все ж в офіційних документах варто використовувати його. У розмовному стилі можна і відповідниками користуватись.